# iOS Activity Indicator when things are being calculated

Tags: ios, uiactivityindicatorview

I am sorry if duplicated the topic but I couldn't find a solution.
I am trying to do some calculations and during performing them I want an user to see the activity indicator just after swiping. To user should see the indicator and wait for textView with results to appear. When I use what I have written then the indicator doesn't show up (I think it shows up and disappears at the same moment). How to get it shown before calcs are started and hide it at the end of my calcs?

```
-(IBAction)swipeRight:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer *) recognizer {
activityIndicator.hidden = NO;
[activityIndicator startAnimating];

//some calculations are being done here
textViewInfo.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"results of long calculations..."];
textViewInfo.alpha = 1;

activityIndicator.hidden = YES;
[activityIndicator stopAnimating];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you are correct in the assumption that the activity indicator is coming up and disappearing at the same moment. All the UI changes are queued to the main thread and are executed when it is time to show UI. As a result, your startAnimating and stopAnimating occur one after the other resulting in "non-appearance" of activity indicator. To counter this, do the following (please check for syntax):-

```
-(IBAction)swipeRight:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer *) recognizer {
    // queue is a NSOperationQueue and is a property of the class
    [queue addOperation: [[NSInvocationOperation alloc] initWithTarget:self selector:@selector(heavyWork) object:nil]];
    [activityIndicator startAnimating];
  }  
    -(void)heavyWork
    {
      //heavy work regarding textView
      [[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] addOperationWithBlock:^{
         activityIndicator.hidden=YES;
      [activityIndicator stopAnimating];}];
    }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, Max! I will check it tomorrow morning. I am sure it will work now.

Comment: I received an error with NSInovacationOperationQueue - Xcode wanted to change it into NSInovacationOperation but then the program stops working… I don't know where the problem is.

Comment: right. It is nsinvocationoperation. I have edited the code

Comment: Yes, of course Xcode changed it without a misspelling. But I still have a problem because the program stops while executing the heavy work. Are you sure everything is fine with your coding? I will check again some other option tomorrow too.

Comment: To be more specific - it stops at Thread 4, 0_WebTryThreadLock(bool) 0x30ad10e:  movl   $0, -1146241297. Thread 4: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0xbbadbeef).

Comment: try making "queue" a property of your class. I have also edited to code to perform UI operation in main thread.

Comment: It stops there again, even if the heavy work regarding textView is removed.

Comment: There must be something else wrong with my code elsewhere. Even if I use code from the topic I duplicated - it still stopping to work at the same place.

Comment: [NSOperationQueue mainQueue]  solved my Problem